# Docker: execute a program that requires tty

Tags: docker, tty

I have a utility program that depends on terminal characteristics. I want to execute it inside a docker container. (the program is not a interactive program as such. It is an old program that was written that way).

`docker run -i -t` or `docker exec -i -t` should open a tty into container. But here is what happens..

```
user@1755e1f3f735:~/region/primer/cobol_v> kickstop
[Error] Unable to run without terminal device (tty)
user@1755e1f3f735:~/region/primer/cobol_v> tty
not a tty
```

When -t option to docker command (run/exec) should give a 'tty', the tty commands returns with 'not a tty'. This is puzzling.

I experienced this on a openSuse and fedora23 hosts and images, if that matters. I used 'guake', MATE (Gnome?) terminal emulators for this, with same results.

Is there any solution to this? or this is by design and have to replace/rewrite my utility?

Comment: Can you post `echo $TERM` when inside your container?

Comment: @user2915097: your question led me to run some experiments. I have 'answered' my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and found "docker exec -ti container script /dev/null" solved the problem.

After login to the container with the above command, I can use screen normally.

Reference: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755

Answer (score 0):

I ran some experiments and here are findings. Hope someone finds them useful.
(docker commands are not complete but just brief)

```
1. docker run -i -t 
> tty
/dev/console
> echo $TERM
xterm
>kickstop
works!!
```

`2. docker -d` followed by `docker exec -i -t`

```
>tty
not a tty
>echo $TERM
dumb
>kickstop
[Error] Unable to run without terminal device (tty)
```

`3. docker -d` followed by `docker attach`
you get attached to /dev/console. No prompt (because I'm running tail -f xxx.log to keep the container alive). In fact I need to stop my application from another terminal (using docker exec) and stop the container to get back to the prompt (host shell)

`4. docker start` followed by `docker attach`
same as above

Comment: and which terminal emulator I use has no bearing on this,